# How to add unremovable copyright text in html Template using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some HTML template, that has developed by HTML CSS Javascript and Jquery. I want to add a copyright text to all of my theme. But there's a fact. If anybody remove the code or text, the theme will be automatically redirect to an URL. I saw this system in Blogger/Blogspot templates. They use a copyright text in all theme footer (Paid and Free). If anybody remove the code/make it invisible (visibility:hidden) or (display:none), the theme automatically redirect. They did it with just jquery and javascript.

How I can do it..?

Comment: removing code will redirect. if so, adding code will act the same?

Comment: It's a tricky question @JShobbyist,,,,, I think It's a tough one to do this. Because anyone can replace the class with another using javascript or jquery.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Anyone can't have access backend of the code. right? Where it will be hosted on?

Comment: @JShobbyist, the code simply will be hosted on cpanel..

Comment: Okay. If so, anyone can't access backend code and can't add javascript or jquery.  right?

Comment: If the user has the power to remove the copyright notice, they have the power to remove any checking code that you put into the frontend too so I can't see how you can possibly do anything in the frontend to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: @AHaworth So If I Encrypted my code, how he can find root code...?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What are you encrypting nd how will the browser run the code? You seem to be asking for a front end solution to this and I just can't see how there can be one

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks, Dan(Example or solution in below answer list) Give a solution where he mentioned that, the browser will check the code in every 10 seconds. If the footer area found, the theme will be normal. If it can't find, the theme will redirect.

Comment: Yes, but the user can remove that code so it gets you nowhere. This really cannot be checked securely on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for any changes within the footer. Try running it, and use your browser's editor to either delete or edit the stuff inside `<footer>` OR you can also try to change the CSS on `<div class="copyright">`. The `setInterval()` timer is set to execute every 10 seconds.

```js
let footer = document.querySelector('footer');
let copyright = document.getElementById('copyright');
let originalFooter = footer.innerHTML;
let originalCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

function checkFooter() {
  let currentFooter = footer.innerHTML;
  let currentCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

  if ((currentFooter !== originalFooter) ||
    (currentCopyrightStyle !== originalCopyrightStyle)) {
    location.href = `https://www.youtube.com/`;
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  checkFooter()
}, 10000);
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="copyright">
    This is my copyright, do not change it!
  </div>
</footer>
```

W3Schools:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
    <div id="copyright">
      This is my copyright, do not change it!
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

<script>
  let footer = document.querySelector('footer');
  let copyright = document.getElementById('copyright');
  let originalFooter = footer.innerHTML;
  let originalCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

  function checkFooter() {
    let currentFooter = footer.innerHTML;
    let currentCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

    if ((currentFooter !== originalFooter) ||
      (currentCopyrightStyle !== originalCopyrightStyle)) {
      location.href = `https://www.youtube.com/`;
    }
  }

  setInterval(() => {
    checkFooter()
    console.log('check');
  }, 1000);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you brother for your initial 
support. I think there's too much way to hack it.       .       1. If anybody set css                               #copyright{display:none;  visibility:hidden;   font-size: 0px;  opacity: 0;   color: transparent;}  Then what can I do.....?

Comment: Thanks for your code. But the problem is, whenever I runs this code on w3 Schools Code Editor (Try it yourselfe), It's not working.  Even when I save this file on my PC and run on Chrome, It's not working. It only works when I change from Inspect option.

Comment: Another things is css Don't have any effect on it. 

Comment: @Dan, I don't think using `setInterval` is not a solution. It runs every 10 seconds and it might cause a low-speed issue on the browser. We may need to use **`DOMSubtreeModified`**. What do you think?

Comment: @JShobbyist Based on the docs, mutation events are depreciated. Additionally, if you read the [preface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent#preface) it mentions that mutation events can have **performance issues** as well as **poor cross-browser support**.

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus, I tried it using VSCode and W3 Schools, and it works for me on both. I've added some code you can paste into W3 Schools.

Comment: Look @Dan, if you run this code on w3Schools editor. It will run. It only redirects when you change the footer text from inspector..... Otherwise it Won't work. If you change the text before running code, and run it, it Won't redirect.  It only works if text Change from inspect.

Comment: But Everyone will change the code from frontend.... Not from inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) and check the element's [`intersectionRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio) to determine whether it's been removed/hidden:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.remove())
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.style.display = "none")

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((elems, obs) => {
  if(elems[0].intersectionRatio == 0) {
    console.log('elem hidden: redirect')
  }
})
observer.observe(copyright)
```

```html
<footer>
  <span id='copyright'> Copyright 2023 - Theme Title </span> | All Rights Reserved.
</footer>

<button id="btn">Remove copyright</button>
<button id="btn1">Hide copyright</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @spectric. I really appreciate your approach. But still not clear your code. Why did you added these button here ?   The code Should like these, if copyright code remove or make it invisible,,, it will redirect to another webpage..

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus The buttons remove and hide the copyright, demonstrating that the code works.

Comment: Thanks @Sepctric, What's the targeted url...?  Where it should be go when redirect...?

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus You replace the console log with the redirect. E.g., `window.location = "url"`

Comment: So the code Should look like that:        console.log('www.google.com')   ?

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus No, you replace `console.log('elem hidden: redirect')` with `window.location = "https://google.com"`

Comment: Thanks @Spectric.. Your code is 90% close that I'm looking for. Just one things is missing. The decoration. 

Comment: When I make it display: none;  it works good. But when set  visibility: hidden;  It's not working.

Comment: And if I remove the copyright id, It's even not working..     
<footer>
 | All Rights Reserved.
</footer>  
 Not redirect..

Comment: It must be like that, if remove the copyright id or not found, it should redirect...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250776/discussion-between-asma-binta-younus-and-spectric).

Comment: Why aren't you not replying me.....?