# How to redirect webpage if copyright text removed using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some HTML template, that has developed by HTML CSS JavaScript and jQuery. I want to add a copyright text to all of my theme. But there's a fact. If anybody remove the code or text, the theme will be automatically redirect to an URL. I saw this system in Blogger/Blogspot templates. They use a copyright text in all theme footer (Paid and Free).

Even if anybody remove the code or make the copyright span invisible (`visibility:hidden`) or (`display:none`), the theme also will be redirect automatically. They did it with just jQuery and JavaScript.

This is my simple code:

```
<footer>
<span id='copyright'> Copyright 2023 - Theme Title </span> | All Rights Reserved. 
</footer>
```

I've also asked this question before Stack Overflow in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828218/how-to-add-unremovable-copyright-text-in-html-template-using-javascript-or-jquer). But they were unable to give me a proper solution.

How I can do it...?